# How to access the $scope where the factory was injected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

Say I have a factory named `MyFactory` and I inject it into several controllers. How can I access the controllers scope inside the factory?

The only way I currently think of on how to do this is as follows:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function() {

    return function($scope) {
        myPublicFunc: function() {
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() { ... });
        }
    }

});

app.controller('MyController1', ['$scope', MyFactory', function($scope, Myfactory) {
    var factory = new MyFactory($scope);
    factory.myPublicFunc();
});
```

But is there any other way where I can just return `{ }` instead of `function($scope) { }` in `MyFactory` and use the factory directly (`MyFactory.myPublicFunc`) instead of having to create a new instance with the `new` keyword **and still access each controller's $scope**?

Comment: services are designed to be shared between scopes and should not have dependencies on controller's scope. I don't think there is a way to do this

Comment: @KhanhTO The example I posted in the question is working, there is that way, at least.

Comment: I was never talking about dependency injection. I just wanted to access the scope inside the factory. I still think I can unit test it, I just need to mock the functions inside the factory, I don't need the scope inside the tests. The *only* reason I need the scope inside the factory is to handle the destroy event so I don't have to replicate code in all controllers that use this specific factory.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a `.service` instead of `.factory` you will already have a singleton instance in a controller once you inject it via DI

and then you can do for example

```
module.service('myService', function() {
    return {
        myPublicFn: function() {}
    }
});
```

and

```
module.controller('myCtrl', function(myService, $scope) {
    $scope.publicFn = myService.myPublicFn;
});
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem. I've updated the question slightly to better explain the issue.

Comment: I think you primarily wanted to get rid of the instantiation of factory... so you want to get rid of scope injecting - that's not a good idea, as @KhanhTO mentioned, services should not have a dependency to any scope, if it has, the logic is not well designed, scope manipulation should remain in the controller

Comment: It's not exactly scope manipulation. I simply don't want to have to replicate the same code for each controller. I need to have the same behavior for the scope destroy event in various controllers. That's the only reason I'm passing the scope to the factory.

Comment: There is one more think you can do in your case... but you probably won't get rid of injecting the scope inside the function call. You can make the service return a plain object and pass the scope into every service method separately. But then you will have to pass scope into each service method called in the controller

Comment: That was my first approach but I didn't like it because of the reasons you just mentioned.

Comment: Yeah I understand... I can't think of any other solution, sorry :(